# drawing connecting nodes where some number of connections occurs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

in neo4j, I'm graphing all nodes that have > x number of connections of relationship `r` with the following query:

```
match (c:Company)-[r:founder]-(x)
with c, count(r) as count where count > 3
return c
```

The above code outputs a graph visualization of company nodes only.

If I try to return all three variables by writing `RETURN c,r,x`, I get the following error:

```
r not defined (line 3, column 12)
"  return c,r,x"
            ^
```

how do i update this query so that I show the company nodes and their founders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work if you do this?

```
match (c:Company)-[r:founder]-(x)
with c, r, x, count(r) as count where count > 3
return c, r, x
```

Comment: I think it answers the question.

Comment: Oh I understand, you need to pass r and x through the WITH clause, otherwise they won't be available after